# Django .url not showing image in template

Tags: django, image, url

I was getting tired of figuring out how to fix this problem. I checked a lot of different posts and answers but nothing helped me.

I have a form where I'm creating new advert. I have file input there for **Image**.
Form is valid and everything works fine, but my problem is that when I want to display my image from **Advert** **model** then it's not showing on website.. even the **alt** text.

My template code:

```
{% for advert in adverts %}
        <img src="{{ advert.get_image }}" alt="test"/>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="mb-4 card">
            <div id="second-advert" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="{{ advert.get_image }}" alt="test"/>
              </div>
            </div>
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('carapp.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = 'carsearch/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

My models.py:

```
class Advert(models.Model):

    def get_image(self):
        if self.featured_image and hasattr(self.featured_image, 'url'):
            return self.featured_image.url
        else:
            return '/path/to/default/image'


    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    [...] <-- there's more code
    featured_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default='profiles/user.png', upload_to='adverts/')
    [...] <-- there's more code



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My project structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo1TC.png)

And my website:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuXtw.png)

The image should appears above these two containers.. but it doesn't.
When I go to admin panel I can see added image in my model and I can click it and see it.
I also can see it in my database with python **shell** and with **DB Browser for SQLite**

But when I inspect the website then I can find my **img** tag but it is disabled(?)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0wer.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2rCA.png)

And my views.py:

```
def adverts(request):
    adverts = Advert.objects.all()

    context = {'adverts': adverts, 'profile': profile}
    return render(request, 'carapp/advertsView.html', context)
```

I tried many things from google and nothing works.. I also can say that I have a Profile form and Profile model. And there is also a photo which I can update and everything works there..

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a solution for this problem. Maybe it’s not what I expected but it helps.

The problem was in my **featured_image** field in models.py. I had to remove the attr **upload_to=“images/adverts”**